# Cordova on android - poor background image scaling using scale3d

Tags: android, css, cordova

I am developing an app using Cordova and have a magazine section which allows the user to slide and zoom into a selection of page images. It works really well and I am pleased with the results in the browser when testing and on iOS.

When a user pinches or double taps the layer with the visible image is scaled using scale3d. The images are large, so when scaling in the browser and on iOS they resample really well and it allows the user to view any text etc.

However, when running the app on Android the image doesn't seem to resample and as a result remaining pixelated and blurry.

I have tried setting the image as a background (size 100%) and having it as an img tag (height, width 100%), but neither seem to resample on Android.

Can anyone suggest a way to get the images to resample on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem similar to this and what I noticed was that devices that supported css 3d transforms and had a pixel density of more than one needed to have hide the `backface-visibility`. I cannot for the life of me explain why that would be.

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

I also noticed on some older devices that didn't have 3d transforms there was some bug with `backface-visibility`, so I couldn't leave it always in. But I sadly don't remember what the bug was.

I ended running Modernizr and just adding in `backface-visibility` above to the elements required like:

```
.csstransforms3d #path .to img { … }
```